# Shell script to produce duplicate output with increments

Tags: shell-script

I need a script that will produce the following output many times

```
@float Figure,fig:n
@cindex 
@image{n,9cm}.
@caption{}
@end float
```

but where n (both times) is replaced by 1, 2, 3, up to a large number.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
seq 1000 | sed 's/.*/@float Figure,fig:&\
@cindex \
@image{&,9cm}.\
@caption{}\
@end float\
/'
```

in a traditional Unix way (see how `seq` and `sed` run at the same time and cooperate to the task).

Comment: Could you expand on the "traditional Unix way" statement?  Is it because it doesn't use the `bash` built-in sequence?

Comment: @garethTheRed, it's about small one-task utilities cooperating to a task. Here one counting tool, one wrapping tool working simultaneously and cooperatively (OK, arguably, `sed` is not a one-task tool). As opposed to invoke a tool hundreds of time and wait for it in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$ for n in {1..10}; do printf '@float Figure,fig:%s
> @cindex
> @image{%s,9cm}.
> @caption{}
> @end float
> ' ${n} ${n}; done
```

Or, as one line:

```
for n in {1..10}; do printf '@float Figure,fig:%s@cindex\n@image{%s,9cm}.\n@caption{}\n@end float\n' ${n} ${n}; done
```

The above prints it 10 times, with no empty lines between each group.  Change the `10` in the curly braces for different numbers.  Add another `\n` at the end of the long `printf` statement for an empty line.

Comment: Better than `cat` as `printf` is generally built-in in most shells (at least on all those that support `$'...'` and `{x..y}` (zsh and recent versions of ksh93 or bash)). Note that you can write the newline characters literally to make it more legible, and you don't need `$'...'` since the `\n` sequences are expanded in `printf`'s format).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I've edited it as per your suggestions. I did wonder about `printf` being a built-in after your reply to my question about your answer.  I bottled out of challenging your opinion though ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop with [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) and any of various ways of producing output. I'll use a [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents):

```
for n in {1..100}
do
    cat <<EOT
@float Figure,fig:$n
@cindex 
@image{$n,9cm}.
@caption{}
@end float
EOT
done
```

This loops over values of `n` from 1 to 100 and prints out that text for each one, with the appropriate values of `n` substituted each time.

If you don't have Bash, `seq 1 100` will have the same effect as the brace expansion; without that, an ordinary loop:

```
i=0; while [ $i -lt 100 ] ; do ... ; i=$((i + 1)) ; done
```

will have the same effect a little less concisely.